# hp-makeuri fails with "device not found"

Tags: arch-linux, printing, cups, hp

I recently did a system update and it upgraded hplip to the latest version and it broke my printing. Before printing to my two networked printers worked fine, now it is broken and none of the cups-based printing works. The printers are set to have static IPs and they work fine. Windows machines on the same network can print to them. I can also print to them on the linux box when I use a C program that writes to the printer IP directly. However, anything that prints via cups fails with no error. For example, if I bring up the cups webadmin it shows both printers as working and ready, and when I test print a page, the webadmin acts as though the page printed successfully, but nothing comes out of the printer.

If I give the following command: hp-makeuri 10.1.10.190 I get the error "Device not found" with no further information.

How can I debug this further?